# native2ascii does not convert correctly when projects are built on Linux

Tags: linux, unicode, maven-plugin

Property before conversion:

CONNECTION_ERROR_OR_SESSIO=Erreur de connexion ou dépassement de session !

Property after conversion:

CONNECTION_ERROR_OR_SESSIO=Erreur de connexion ou d\u00c3\u00a9passement de session !

Plugin converts é to \u00c3\u00a9 instead of \u00e9

```
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>native2ascii-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-alpha-1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>native2ascii-utf8-resources</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>native2ascii</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <dest>src/temp</dest>
                        <src>src</src>
                        <ext>.properties</ext>
                        <encoding>ISO-8859-1</encoding>
                        <includes>MessageResource_fr_FR.properties                   
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
       </plugins>
```

This happens only on Linux. It works fine when the projects are built on Windows. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

That means during some step your build chain reads a file assuming it is ISO-8859-1, while the file is actually encoded in UTF-8.

`é` is *U+00E9 — LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE*

the UTF-8 encoding of that character is `"\xc3\xa9"`. If you read those bytes back as ISO-8859-1 the result are the two characters *U+00C3* `'Ã'` and *U+00E9* `'é'`. And those characters are the ones you're seeing in the converted file.

If you're supporting a lot of languages, then the probability you can encode all of them in ISO-8859-1 is vanishingly small. If at all possible, just encode all those files as UTF-8.